# Identify this weed

Tags: weed-control, weeds

[image: Weed]
[image: Weed flower]
The weed spreads out like a vine below the grass in the lawn and has a long root and pink flowers.

Edit: 
[image: grass with weed in it]
Here is a picture with the grass with the weed in it. You can see it at the bottom of the image.

I'm in South East, Queensland

Comment: Something in direction of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonum_aviculare. Could you make a better photo of the flower? Put something just behind the flower, to force focus.

Comment: It looks a lot like something we have in my area (Western USA) called "burr clover". The flowers on our weed are yellow, not pink, but the leaves in your photo do look like some kind of weedy clover. perhaps related to a "Medicago", "alfalfa" type species?

Comment: Were you able to go break a stem of that weed?  Does it have white sap?

Comment: What grasses are your neighbors using?  This lawn doesn't look like there is a single grass growing.  What is the scale on your lawn picture?  Someone on this site will know more than I do about what you've got for a lawn.  Please check on that sap stuff, okay?

Answer (score 1):

[Prostrate spurge or spotted spurge or creeping spurge](http://www.better-lawn-care.com/prostrate-spurge.html)

Chamaesyce maculata or Euphorbia supina.  Hope this helps.  Where is it that you live, what zone?  I am guessing you have warm season grasses? Knowing the proper maintenance of the crop you are growing for a lawn will help so very much to suppress any weeds.  One should not have to use herbicide, really ever and I am a 3 decade long licensed commercial pesticide applicator  Missing the spot on these leaves as well so wait for others to help out as well.

Please send a picture of your entire lawn, the zone you live in, your maintenance practices, how often you fertilize, how short you mow your crop, what your watering practices are?

Here is another possible ID.  Prostrate Knotweed...the distinctive difference would be the Spurge will have a milky sap.  Do not get on skin.  If no milky sap then not a spurge.
[Prostrate Knotweed](http://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/WEEDS/common_knotweed.html)

Comment: I've added a photo of the grass. I'm in South East Queensland. I don't think it's Chamaesyce maculata cause I think I have that as well at this weed is a bit different it's hides under the grass. With maintenance practices I can't really answer that I've only just moved into the place, in the photo the grass has just been mowed.

Comment: Have you always lived in Australia?  I think I am going to learn more about lawns, today...this doesn't look like any kind of grass, at all.  Tried to blow the picture up...does this 'lawn' flower or have seed heads??  Other than the weed you want to know about...I thought I knew everything about lawns, ha ha ha!!